# Android onClick(View v) not working?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm stuck at a point and would really appreciate it if anyone could please help me. I'm developing an app which has a grid of colored rectangles. These are created by changing the background colors of a number of TextViews. There are 3 Buttons which cause the background color to change according to some algorithm. There are also 2 TextViews which show the current status of the game.

Now the problem is I have a button example (one of the three buttons) which is supposed to change the background color of the rectangles.

```
example.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) { 
         status_val.setText("true board-example working");
         level_1_true(); 
     }
});
```

The `level_1_true()` method sets the background color of the rectangles. The above code results in an `"activity not responding"` dialog being shown, and the `OnClickListener` does not change the view. Someone suggested I try the `runOnUIThread` method in activity, but I can't get it to do what I want it to do.

How do I change the view of the screen by clicking the button?

Comment: Using proper spelling and vowels would make it a lot easier for someone to understand your question.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code, if you fix it (press 'edit' on your question) and use proper formatting, more people will be able to help. Here's how to format your code in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you please post the details of what's happening in the `level_1_true()` method?

Comment: log and more code would be help. Try to change new Button.OnClickListener() to new View.OnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding in your button xml code android:onClick="onClickMethod" and adding  in your activity

```
public void onClickMethod(View v) { 
         status_val.setText("true board-example working");
         level_1_true(); 
     }
```

How did you define status_val? You remeber to link it like this?

status_val=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.);

Please tell me if I can be of more help